# Saving a Jfreechart to my database

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using Jfreechart to create a chart. I am displaying this on a swing. I want to save this chart and upload it onto my database. Does anyone know how to do this. If it is not possible what other library can i use for achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to save the graph as a PNG:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;

JFreeChart myChart = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, myChart, width, height);
```

and then store that byte array as a BLOB in your DB.